Nested grouping variables for stacked bar graph
I'm trying to improve the visualization of this figure by separating the x-axis into nested subcategories of samples. I'm not able to use ggplot fill for this since I've already used pivot_longer() to include 6 types of output. The solution also has to allow a free scale view using facet_wrap() to examine trends between individual protein components.
Have:

Want:

Attempt:

Data frame:
>head(data)
>  ShortName  Mod Growth Day    Group        Conc
>1  CTRL_D02 CTRL     CC   2 Protein1 0.013072917
>2  CTRL_D02 CTRL     CC   2 Protein2 0.000000000
>3  CTRL_D02 CTRL     CC   2 Protein3 0.004661458
>4  CTRL_D02 CTRL     CC   2 Protein4 0.000000000
>5  CTRL_D02 CTRL     CC   2 Protein5 0.000000000
>6  CTRL_D02 CTRL     CC   2 Protein6 0.025885417

>CC <- data %>% slice(1:144)
>LG <- data %>% slice(145:210)

ggplot, stacked bar graph to view broad quantity of all proteins
p0 <- ggplot(CC) + 
  geom_col(aes(x = ShortName, y = Conc, fill = Group)) + 
  theme_clean() + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1)) + 
  labs(y = "Concentration", x = "Sample", fill = "Composition")

ggplot, view trends of individual protein components
p0.1 <- p0 + 
  facet_wrap(. ~ Group, scales = "free_y") + 
  theme(legend.position="none")


Looks like you want to use Mod not Group in your facet_wrap().

And you'll need a column in your data with the x-axis values that you want, which seem to be just the end of the ShortName.

You are very close. Perhaps just ggplot(CC, aes(Day, Conc, fill = Group)) + geom_col() + facet_wrap(vars(Mod), scales = 'free')? Make sure Day is a factor or character vector.

Thank you @GregorThomas and @Axeman, I was able to get my desired plot using an interaction term for Mod and Day and the package ggh4x.

You can use the ggh4x package to do the nesting of the x-axis tick labels.
library(ggplot2); library(ggh4x)

ggplot(data, aes(x=interaction(Day,Mod), Conc, fill = Group)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  scale_x_discrete(guide="axis_nested") +  # *** ggh4x *** #
  facet_grid(~Mod, scales = 'free') +
  labs(x="Sample", y="Concentration", fill="Composition", 
       title="Stacked bar graph of convoluted timecourse") +
  #theme_clean() +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
        strip.text = element_blank(),
        axis.line.x = element_line(),
        axis.line.y = element_line(),
        legend.box.background = element_rect())



data <- tibble(Day=sample(c('D02','D04','D07','D11','D02','D14'), 210, TRUE),
                   Mod=sample(c('CTRL','P2E8','P2G7','poly'), 210, TRUE),
                   Growth=sample(c('CC','LG'), 210, TRUE),
                   Group=sample(paste0("Protein", 1:6), 210, TRUE, prob=c(10,1,1,1,1,1)),
                   Conc=runif(210, 0, 0.3))


Thanks so much! Adding an interaction term and using ggh4x gave me the desired outplot.

The way I've done this is to create a numerical variable in the dataframe that I can map to the x-axis, and then re-create the labels in scale_x_continuous by looking up the labels using that value. Here's a crude example using a fake dataset.
set.seed(123)

data <- data.frame(
  ShortName = sample(c( "D02", "D04", "D07", "D09", "D11", "D14"), 1250, replace = TRUE), 
  Mod = sample(c("CTRL", "P2E8", "P2G7", "poly"), 1250, replace = TRUE), 
  #Growth = sample(c("CC", "LG"), 1250, replace = TRUE), 
  #Day = sample(2:14, 1250, replace = TRUE),
  Group = sample(c("Protein1", "Protein2", "Protein3", "Protein4", "Protein5", "Protein6"), 1250, replace = TRUE),
  Conc = runif(1250, 0, 1)
) %>% 
  summarise(.by = c(-Conc), Conc = mean(Conc))

data <- data   %>%
  arrange(ShortName, Mod, Group) %>%
  mutate(
  ShortName = factor(ShortName),
  Mod = factor(Mod),
  xpos = (as.numeric(Mod))* 7 + (as.numeric(ShortName)),
  l = paste(ShortName, Mod, sep = "_")
  ) 

getlabel <- function(x){
  d <- (data[data$xpos == x,c("ShortName","Mod")][1,])
  paste(d$ShortName, d$Mod, sep = "\n")
}
getlabel <- Vectorize(getlabel)

data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = xpos)) + 
  geom_col(aes(y = Conc, fill = Group)) +
  scale_x_continuous(
    breaks = unique(data$xpos), 
    labels = getlabel(unique(data$xpos))
    )+
  labs(x = "sample", y = "concentration")

